# How to extract the frequency components of a function in Julia

Tags: julia, fft

I'm trying to be able to extract the frequency components of some arbitrary function.
I think this problem involves some sort of Fourier transform, but it's not exactly clear to me the proper way to use this, especially in Julia.

I tried winging it by just throwing a pure sine function into an FFT, and without any surprise on my part, it didn't give any usable results.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your function is returning the raw numeric data, you can use DSP.jl for the analysis:

```
using DSP

data = myfunc()

@show periodogram(data)
@show spectrogram(data)  # could plot this as well
```